# IFS with more than three conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, excel, performance

This formula looks correct to me but it has failed to work for me,

`=IFS(M2=0,"PAR0",M2>0,"PAR1",M2>7,"PAR7",M2>14,"PAR14",M2>30,"PAR30",M2>60,"PAR60",M2>90,"PAR90")`

I expect it to return the PAR(s) but its only giving me 0 and 1, what could be the issue with it

Comment: Please provide more context. Please also format code to make it more readable.

Comment: Make a table of data and use vlookup(). Easier to see and edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if a value is 0 then it stops at the first found match which is PAR0 and if the value is greater than 0 then it stops at the second condition and outputs PAR1. The order in IFS condition is very important.
You need to reverse the logical conditions, starting from highest and then going to the lowest...something like below. Below it is H2 but you may want to change it to M2.

```
=IFS(H2>90,"PAR90",H2>60,"PAR60",H2>30,"PAR30",H2>14,"PAR14",H2>7,"PAR7",H2>0,"PAR1",H2=0,"PAR0")
```

An example data and output is as in the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So using vlookup:

[image]

The data table is easy to control.

Vlookup gets the result from column 2 of the data table.

C2 is the function in B2 and dragged down for the other examples.

Here it is as text:

```
VLOOKUP(A2,D$3:E$9,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for INDEX/MATCH.

```
="PAR"&INDEX({0,1,7,14,30,60,90},MATCH(M2,{0,1,7,14,30,60,90},1))
```

The first array 0 to 90 is the index. The Match function returns an evaluation of M2 relative to its own array. The formula returns the nth value from the index, where n is the result from the MATCH function. You can test the latter separately.

The evaluation is based on =>. Therefore if M2 contains exactly 7 *PAR7* will be returned. 6 returns *PAR1*. If you need *PAR7* to kick in only for numbers above 7 change the array for the MATCH function as follows.

```
MATCH(M2,{0,1,8,15,31,61,91},1)
```