# How to calculate value based on tax bracket using Google sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, calculation

I want to calculate the tax on the amount based on tax bracket applied to it in Google sheet. Here is the screenshot of the tax bracket:
[image: Tax Bracket]

So if the amount is **$17000**, then 10.5% tax is applied on first $14000 and 17.50% tax should be applied on the remaining $3000. I have tried the following formula but I don't think this is the optimal way of calculating this, J13 cell has a value to be calulated for the taxable amount:

```
=IFS(J8<14001,14000*0.105,J8<48001,1470+(J8-14000)*0.175,J8<70001,7420+(J8-48000)*0.30) and so on for other tax ranges
```

I donot want to use this tax table in the formula, due to my beginner skills with the formulas, I am unable to devise a optimal formula which works without using tac table, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: So use a vlookup() and a table of data. So many examples on here that I won’t add another.

Comment: yes, I tried vloop up but I could not find ranges condition. i.e 0-14000, 14001-48000.
the examples cover the ranges like 14000, 48000

Comment: So don’t put ranges - just the highest figure for each band.

Comment: See this as it is exactly how you need to use vlookup(): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65273236/4961700

Comment: the only issue is , I want to do it without adding table in google sheet

Comment: Then define the arrays in vlookup. Examples exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Sheets here's one approach. Please do test it out with various scenarios to see if there's any amiss..

- arrange the tax table as shown in `Columns A,B,C`
- the calculation behind the formula for this example scenario (amount of `$17000`) is

  `(14000*10.5%)+((17000-14001)*17.5%)` = `1994.825`

***Formula:***

```
=ROUND(SUM(MAP(A1:A5,B1:B5,{C1:C4;99^99},LAMBDA(a,b,c,IFs(E1>c,c-b,E1>b,E1-b,TRUE,"")*a))),2)
```

[image]

***Another approach:***

```
=lambda(z,offset(z,2,0)+((E1-z)*offset(z,1,0)))(index(G1:K1,xmatch(E1,G1:K1,-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, as I mentioned in my comments can we do it without using this tax table?

Comment: doesn't your `ifs` formula already do that?! is it something specific you are looking for...

Comment: yes, my if formula works without table and I need to optimize it if possible, thank you

Comment: I believe I have to use this table for optimal solution, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating your table with curly brackets inside your formula. Use comma for dividing percentage and value, and semicolons to divide the different percentages. You can hav a first line with the value 0 and the last one with 999^99 which is an ultra-high value for the case when you overpass $180.000:

```
=LAMBDA(table,LET(l,MATCH(B1,INDEX(table,,2),1),INDEX(table,l,2)*INDEX(table,l,1)+(B1-INDEX(table,l,2))*INDEX(table,l+1,1)))
({10.5%,0;
10.5%,14000;
17.5%,48000;
30%,70000;
33%,180000;
39%,999^99})
```

[image]

As an array:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(B1:B),LAMBDA(table,LET(l,MATCH(B1:B,INDEX(table,,2),1),INDEX(table,l,2)*INDEX(table,l,1)+(B1:B-INDEX(table,l,2))*INDEX(table,l+1,1)))
({10.5%,0;
10.5%,14000;
17.5%,48000;
30%,70000;
33%,180000;
39%,999^99}),""))
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are needlessly over-complicated. Use this named function:

> **TAX**(*taxable*, *brackets*)
>
> Computes the tax on a given taxable amount according to specified tax brackets.
>
> - *taxable*: The amount to be taxed. Example: `69420`.
> - *brackets*: A 2-column array in which the first column contains the bracket cutoffs and the second column contains the tax rates. Example: `{0,10%; 11000,12%; 44725,22%; 95375,24%; 182100,32%; 231250,35%; 578125,37%}`.
>
> ```
> =LET(
>   n, ROWS(brackets),
>   bounds, CHOOSECOLS(brackets, 1),
>   rates, CHOOSECOLS(brackets, 2),
>   SUMPRODUCT(
>     MAP(bounds, LAMBDA(bound, MAX(taxable - bound, 0))),
>     MMULT(ARRAYFORMULA(MUNIT(n) - MAKEARRAY(n, n, LAMBDA(r, c, r = c + 1))), rates)
>   )
> )
> ```

To compute the tax in OP's example:

```
=TAX(17000, {0,10.5%; 14000,17.5%; 48000,30%; 70000,33%; 180000,39%})
```

The meat of the calculation is the `SUMPRODUCT` call, which is passed two arrays. The first array contains the amounts by which the taxable amount exceeds each bracket cutoff (or 0 if the amount is less than the cutoff). The second array contains the incremental tax-rate contributions of each successive bracket.

In OP's example, the two arrays passed to `SUMPRODUCT` would be:

- `{17000; 3000; 0; 0; 0}`
- `{10.5%; 7%; 12.5%; 3%; 6%}`

The tax is the sum of the products of corresponding elements in the two arrays:
17000×10.5% + 3000×7% + 0×12.5% + 0×3% + 0×6% = 1995.

Answer (score 1):

This is less clever than other answers, but could be easier for some to grok, and I believe it matches the requirements of the original poster ...

```
=SUM(
  IF( GT(J13,180000), 0.39*(J13-180000),            0 ),
  IF( GT(J13,70000),  0.33*(MIN(J13,180000)-70000), 0 ),
  IF( GT(J13,48000),  0.3*(MIN(J13,70000)-48000),   0 ),
  IF( GT(J13,14000),  0.175*(MIN(J13,48000)-14000), 0 ),
  IF( GT(J13,0),      0.105*(MIN(J13,14000)-0),     0 ),
)
```

**Note:** The `J13` cell reference and tax bracket figures are matched to details mentioned in the original post.

Comment: This one is worth of my thumbs up for being a friendly solution for non-savvy people.

Answer (score 0):

I've rearranged [*rockinfreakshow*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75577356/13180090) it in a `LET` expression so it is easy to customize:

```
=LET(
  value_, income,
  upper_limits, WRAPROWS(limits,1),
  rates_, WRAPROWS(rates,1),
  lower_limits, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(upper_limits),1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r >1,INDEX(upper_limits,r-1,c),0))),
  SUM(
    MAP(
      lower_limits, upper_limits, rates_, 
      LAMBDA(lower, upper, rate,
        IFS(
          AND(upper > 0, value_ > upper), upper - lower, 
          value_ > lower, value_ - lower, 
          TRUE, 0
        )*rate
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Change the variables `income`, `limits` and `rates` accordingly.
I recommend defining a [named function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534?hl=en) like I've done in this [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EHlTomxv6wmxrrzTR4oaNwDfHOJA4zn6BkXGDqZ9sdw/edit?usp=sharing)
[image]